# Eclipse 4 reuse toolbar for different parts

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4

I've build about 10-15 Parts in differenet PartStacks. Every Part should have some Handled Tool Item, 4 of them are identical.
Because of this I want to reuse this 4 toolbar-items without adding them manually to every part.

In Eclipse 3.x we had build these toolbars via inheritance - each view, which should have this toolbar-items extends a class, which adds these items.

Is there a proper way to have a "toolbar-template"?

Any ideas wanted ;)

Cheers, Steffen

**SOLUTION**: (thanks greg)

Thank you Greg, the Processor worked.

Here is the corresponding code:

```
@Inject
@Named("de.test.myperspective")
private MPerspective perspective;

@Inject
private MApplication application;

@Execute
public void execute(EModelService modelService) {
    if (perspective != null) {
        List<MPart> parts = modelService.findElements(perspective, null,
                MPart.class, null);
        for (MPart part : parts) {
            MUIElement snip = modelService.cloneSnippet(application,
                    "de.test.mytoolbarsnippet", null);
            MToolBar toolbar = (MToolBar) snip;
            part.getToolbar().getChildren()
                    .addAll(0, toolbar.getChildren());
        }
    }
}
```

In the fragment.xmi I added a new ModelFragment to Application->Snippets and added a Toolbar with ID "de.test.mytoolbarsnippet" there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `Snippet` in your application model.

Use the `EModelService` `cloneSnippet` method to create the controls from the snippet.

You might do this in a Processor running on the application model - see the `org.eclipse.e4.workbench.model` extension point `processor` element.